# Check cells in table for value "x" and transfer each in new table

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a big dataset which I'm showing here simplified:
[image]

I need to check the cells in the columns C to E whether they have an "x" value.
If they do, I need to transfer them in a second table, as well as their corresponding value in the columns A and B.

The outcome should look like this:
[image]

I tried If-functions as well as INDEX-functions and VBA coding.

My problem is, that if you got more than one "x" value in a line, I don't know how to return both the first and the second cells as well as for both cells their corresponding values in A and B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OP has tagged **`Excel`** and if one is using `MS365` then can use the following formula:

[image]

---

```
=HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(C2:E4="x",C1:E1),3),TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&TOCOL(IFS(C2:E4="x",B2:B4&"|"&A2:A4),3),"|",{1,2}),"|"))
```

---

Using <kbd>LET()</kbd> to make readability easier,

```
=LET(
     α, TOCOL(IFS(C2:E4="x",C1:E1),3),
     φ, TOCOL(IFS(C2:E4="x",B2:B4&"|"&A2:A4),3),
     HSTACK(α,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&φ,"|",{1,2}),"|")))
```

---

**Note:** Formulas shown above won't work with `Structured References` since it will give `#SPILL!` error.

---

This can be accomplished quickly and easily using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>. To achieve this using the said procedure, follow this simple steps using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> window `UI`:

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Name", "Value"}, "Attribute", "Value.1"),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute", "Value", "Name", "Value.1"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"Value.1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Attribute", "Frame"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

[image]

---

Comment: That worked out just fine with Power Query, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to know that!

Answer (score 0):

The coding for this is straight forward and I don't know what to explain. It reads the data into memory (2-dimensional array), creates a result array, loops over the data, fills the result array and finally writes the result array into Excel.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertMyData(sourceRange As Range, destRange As Range)
    ' read data into memory
    Dim data, row As Long, col As Long
    data = sourceRange.CurrentRegion.Value
    
    ' Count number of needed results values
    Dim rowcount As Long
    rowcount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sourceRange.CurrentRegion, "x")
    If rowcount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Nothing selected."
        Exit Sub           ' Nothing marked with x
    End If
    
    ' Create result array
    ReDim result(1 To rowcount + 1, 1 To 3) As Variant
    Dim resultRow As Long
    
    ' Prepare Header
    result(1, 1) = "Frame"
    result(1, 2) = "Value"
    result(1, 3) = "Name"
    
    ' Fill result array
    resultRow = 2
    For row = 2 To UBound(data, 1)
        For col = 3 To UBound(data, 2)
            If data(row, col) = "x" Then
                result(resultRow, 1) = data(row, 2) ' Value
                result(resultRow, 2) = data(1, col) ' Caption (eg "frame 1")
                result(resultRow, 3) = data(row, 1) ' Name
                resultRow = resultRow + 1
            End If
        Next col
    Next row
    
    ' write result
    destRange.Resize(UBound(result, 1), 3) = result
End Sub
```

Call the routine with something like this - adapt the worksheet(s) and ranges to your needs:

```
Sub testx()
    ConvertMyData ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("G1")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Unpivot: Column Labels and Row Labels, and Values As Flags

```
=LET(data,A1:E7,row_labels,{2;1},flag,"x",if_not_found,"",
    rCols,COUNT(row_labels),
    d,DROP(data,1),
    rRows,ROWS(d),
    rl,CHOOSECOLS(d,row_labels),
    cl,DROP(TAKE(data,1),,rCols),
    cCols,COLUMNS(cl),
    cs,TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(rRows),cl)),
    rs,CHOOSEROWS(rl,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(rRows*cCols)/cCols,)),
FILTER(HSTACK(cs,rs),TOCOL(DROP(d,,rCols))=flag,if_not_found))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My approach is here..

```
=LET(nm,A3:A5,val,B3:B5,fr,C2:E2,op,(IF(C3:E5="","",nm&","&val&","&fr)),
VSTACK(HSTACK("name","value",""),WRAPROWS(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("-",,op),,{",",",","-"}),3)))
```

[image: Result]